# org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Result must not be null @Query SpringBoot Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-boot

Уже несколько часов сижу с этим багом.. Перерыл много сайтов, весь SoF просмотрел, именно такой проблемы, как у меня нет ни у кого.

мой JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone=:p", nativeQuery = true)
fun findByPhoneNumber(@Param(value="p") p : String) : User

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?", nativeQuery = true)
fun findByEmail(email: String): User

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE displayName=?", nativeQuery = true)
fun findByUsername(username: String): User
}
```

для теста я пока использовал findByPhoneNumber и это приводит к ошибке:

```html
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Result must not be null
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Result must not be null
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy106.findByPhoneNumber(Unknown Source)
    at ru.bladegames.api.service.UserService.getUserBy(UserService.kt:20)
    at ru.bladegames.api.controller.UserController.loginUser(UserController.kt:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

и вот, параметр "p" не читается в @Query.. Как я только не пробовал, и :p, и (:p), и ?1.. Ничего не помогает.. Но если ввести сразу номер в запрос, т.е так:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone=+77777777777", nativeQuery = true)
fun findByPhoneNumber(@Param(value="p") p : String) : User
```

то проблем никаких нет и пользователь находится по номеру и выводится JSON'ом...

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим? Может это я что-то упустил из виду?

upd. это проблема передачи номера телефона. Если в адресной строке ввести username или email, аккаунт по ним находится. а номер телефона только если прописать в коде... очень странно.. может какие-то ограничения есть?

Answer (score 0):

EmptyResultDataAccessException - это нормально. Т.е. на ваш запрос ничего не нашлось. Немного настораживает знак "+" в номере.
Поднимитесь на уровень выше в сервис и попробуйте там вызвать

```
userRepository.findByPhoneNumber("+77777777777")
```

Скорее всего так тоже сработает и нужная вам запись найдется.

Идем в контроллер. И вот тут нас ждет засада. В параметрах строки запроса `+` это пробел. И ваш номер в контроллер приходит как  `77777777777`.
Для символа `+` передаем его код `%2B`. Т.е. `%2B77777777777`.

Прошу извинить, если моя телепатия сработала не верно :)

Comment: Я уже нашел причину. Но тут дело даже не в этом.. 
Даже если без плюса вводил бы, ничего не получалось.
Я строку освободил от пробелов (trim()) и еще сконвертировал в Long (toLong).
Так все прекрасно работает. Я так и не понял почему напрямую со стринга он не хотел нормально читать, ну да ладно